# vmware remove partition from datastore

Tags: vmware-esxi

I got a datastore which consists of 2 partitions on different hdds. I freed enough space to store everything in the datastore on the first hdd.

How can I move all data to the first partition and remove the second one from the datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extent can never be removed from a datastore.  See [here](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1003344%E2%80%8E).

To get the single partition into a datastore by itself, you'll need to move all VMs off the datastore temporarily, destroy and re-create it as a new datastore, then move the VMs back.